# Spring Data JPA CrudRepository method naming confusion

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

Suppose a table "Users" contains a column name "User_Id"

So I will name the method as **UserEntity findByUserId(String UserId)**; ....

But if there is a another column named "UserId" then which column will get the preference?

Example table looks like this :

```
Id    User_Id    UserId   Name

1     xdf23e     xdf23e   testuser
```

Comment: The table is irrelevant. What matters is your entity. But quite frankly, whether it's the table or the entity, having a column/property named UserId and another one named User_Id is really a terrible, terrible idea. You're **looking** for bugs and problems by doing that.

Comment: I agree with your opinion, I just wanted to know what actually happens..and You cleared by doubt by saying " What matters is your entity" .. Thanks :)

Comment: always use unique Id for this. So it will not be duplicated at all.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with what JB Nizet says. Having said that:
First, I would always use came case for entity fields.  ( See spring doc

[Spring data documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#reference)
Because we treat the underscore character as a reserved character, we strongly advise following standard Java naming conventions (that is, not using underscores in property names but using camel case instead).

If that is not possible, you can escape an underscore in field name by double underscores (__).

Answer (score 0):

As @JB Nizet explained "**What matters is your entity**",

just further adding to that, considering an example of JPA with hibernate, JPA/Hibernate will generate names based on your entity. In case you have two columns in the database that doesn't matter, you can always have different names in your entity and map them to the correct column using @Column annotation.